# How to build a range of locations with defined parameters?

Tags: python

I have a very basic programming background, but have been given a quick task to have a program that can take a source and destination location and essentially spit out the range of all locations between the source and destination.

I built the input GUI, and have all variables passed into a function, now I just need to figure out how to loop through this correctly.

The location is in this form (without the spaces): `XXXXXXXXXXX 001 X 01 01`

The Xs are hard coded based on the values I pass in. The last entry should scale first. I also have an entry for the max value possible in each of last 2 fields.

Example source: `XXXXXXXXXXX003X0102`

Example Destination: `XXXXXXXXXXX004X0201`

In this case the program would spit out the following based on the range between 003 and 004 with a max range of 03 and 02 for the last 2 positions (will add spaces to make easier to read):

[ranges using the inputs and maximums is `"XXXXXXXXXXX 003->004 X 01->03 01->02"`]

```
XXXXXXXXXXX 003 X 01 02
XXXXXXXXXXX 003 X 02 01
XXXXXXXXXXX 003 X 02 02
XXXXXXXXXXX 003 X 03 01
XXXXXXXXXXX 003 X 03 02
XXXXXXXXXXX 004 X 01 01
XXXXXXXXXXX 004 X 01 02
XXXXXXXXXXX 004 X 02 01
```

Right now I was able to create a GUI to input all of these value and pass them to a function.

I am thinking this will best 3 nested for loops using the ranges from the input, but I am really confused on how to increment with leading 0s coupled with the conditional max values while being nested within the loops.

Pseudo unfinished code->

```
def addressGenerator(bMax, cMax, X, sourceA, sourceB, sourceC, destinationA, destinationB, destinationC):
    for x in range(sourceA, destinationA):
        for y in range(01, bMax):
            for z in range(01, cMax):
                # content
```

Comment: is this some kind of counter? you increment by 1 till max for that pos reached? I dont quite get it...

Comment: Why does the `addressGenerator()` have two `destinationB` parameters? Please add  an example of a call it that shows the format of all the arguments passed.

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks

Comment: How do all those parameters map to the problem? How are they used to form the output?

Comment: X - > XXXXXXXXXXX A->003 X B->01 C->02, the max B and max C value make B and C have a range from 01->max, and the output is going to be writing to a text file all of these addresses in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it. The three ranges are passed as tuples each containing the start and end values (inclusive) desired. I also added a `separator` parameter since it looks like there's a stray unexplained "X" in the output shown in your question.

**Update:** Modified as to impose limits per your comments below about the meaning of "source" and "destination", plus removed previous caveat.

The code is borderline unreadable in my opinion, and could probably be refactored—but as I said, I believe it (now) accomplishes your goal.

One improvement to it's usability might be to make it parse the `src` and `dst` string arguments and determine the intervals automatically.

```
def addressGenerator(prefix, separator, src, dst, interval1, interval2, interval3):
    minval, maxval = int(src), int(dst)

    for x in range(interval1[0], interval1[1]+1):
        for y in range(interval2[0], interval2[1]+1):
            for z in range(interval3[0], interval3[1]+1):
                v = x * 10000 + y * 100 + z
                if minval <= v <= maxval:
                    pieces = prefix, '%03d' % x, separator, '%02d' % y, '%02d' % z
                    yield ''.join(pieces)

# Sample usage.
for address in addressGenerator('XXXXXXXXXXX', 'Y',
                                '0030102', '0040201', (3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2)):
    print(address)
```

Output:

```
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0102
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0201
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0202
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0301
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0302
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0101
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0102
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0201
```

Comment: Great reply! Thanks. The one thing missing is how you can start and end in the middle of the interval2 and interval3 range. For example the source could be your second output "XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0102" and the destination may be your second-to-last output "XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0301". So the total range is key, but the start and finish may not sure the entire range.

Comment: Tsyras: Sorry, I don't quite understand. You keep using the terms "source" and "destination" which is unclear to me. In my code there are three "intervals" being passed, each with beginning and ending values. Try to explain what you want in those terms if possible, please.

Comment: Basically, I am inputting 2 unique locations (the source and destination), and I need this to output all locations between these 2. So if the source was XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0102 and the destination was XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0201 then the output would be:

XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0102
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0201
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0202
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0301
XXXXXXXXXXX003Y0302
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0101
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0102
XXXXXXXXXXX004Y0201

Comment: Tsyras: OK, think I got it now.

Comment: Tsyras: the `x * 10000 + y * 100 + z` converts the current values of `x`, `y`, and `z,` into a single numeric value for use in the following conditional statement. The `minval <= v <= maxval` is a legal Python boolean expression checking to see if this calculated value is within the limits established by the `src` and `dst` arguments (which correspond to `minval` and `maxval` respectively).

Answer (score 1):

For now, don't worry about leading zeros. Instead, use integers to maintain your counts, and then use formatted print statements to insert the zeros for you:

```
for x in range(3,5):
    for y in range(1,4):
       for z in range(2,5):
          print("XXXX{:03d}XX{:02d}{:02d}".format(x, y, z))
```

Comment: My problem is that the y and z can start and end in the middle of their range, but as they increment x or y respectively then they start back at 01 until they reach their range (and eventually reach the final location).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, but your `addressGenerator` function has too many parameters for me. Let's say you could split the source and destination strings into tuples like `(XXXXXXXXXXX, 003, X, 01, 02)`. And then you had a function which just took the source and destination tuples.

So these are the indexes in the tuple:

```
 0            1    2  3   4
(XXXXXXXXXXX, 003, X, 01, 02)
```

What I think you want is to loop between the indexes `source[1] -> destination[1]`; `source[3] -> destination[3]`; and `source[4] -> destination[4]`. Which is broadly what you already have. Then you can format the different things with padding.

```
def get_addresses(source, destination):
    for a in range(int(source[1]), int(destination[1]):
        for b in range(int(source[3]), int(destination[3])):
            for c in range(int(source[4]), int(destination[4])):
                yield '{}{:03d}{}{:02d}{:02d}'.format(source[0], a, source[2], b, c)
```

Comment: The problem is that they are not independent, using your example indices, when 4 reaches the max possible value it increments 3 and starts over, and when 3 reaches the max possible value it increments 1 and starts over, and the source address may not start at 01 and the destination may not end at the max (even though all locations in the middle need to account for starting at 01 and ending at max).